# How to install same libraries in different name

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am Japanese web developer and I am not good at English , sorry.

I am using library by npm.

I forked the library and I remade it.

I changed my package.json like this.

"libraryName": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master",

"npm install" worked properly.

But now I want to import same library in different name.

I want to subtend them by branches.

package.json

```
"libraryName1": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master1",
"libraryName2": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master2",
```

TypeScript

```
 import library as libraryName1 from "libraryName1";
 import library as libraryName2 from "libraryName2";
```

I want to do something like this.
Anyone know the way to do this?

What I tried.↓

1.yarn install -g

2.yarn add lodash2@npm:lodash@2.x

3.edit package.json like this.

```
"libraryName1": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master1",
"libraryName2": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master2",
```

4.yarn add libraryName1

↑ error occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with npm currently. You could use yarn instead of npm to solve this. Otherwise you need to publish your own npm package.

package.json example to install both bootstrap 3 and 4. This only works with yarn.

`"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap3": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#3.3.7"
}`

Sources:

- [Install multiple versions of a dependency #5499](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499)
- [Yarn tip: You can alias a package by using...](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/873958422605164544)

Comment: can you provide any source for this?

Comment: If I did "yarn add lodash2@npm:lodash@2.x" will I be able to install library like this? "libraryName1": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master1",
"libraryName2": "git+https://github.com/MyGitName/libraryName#master2",

Comment: @nichika I've added an package.json example.

Comment: Thank you! But I think since bootstrap and bootstrap3 are different packages , it is possible. In my case , libraryName1 and libraryName2 are same library but remade it differently by different branches.

Comment: @nichika They are not different packages. You can also do this 

`"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap4": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap",
    "bootstrap": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#3.3.7"
  }`

Comment: Thank you. Then , if I did "yarn install" after I wrote something like this on package.json , are they both would be added to nodemodules?

Comment: @nichika Yes they are. You can browse `node_modules` folder and check the package.json file for each package to see if it's correct.

Comment: Oh my gosh!!!!!!!!!! It worked properly!!!!! Thank you sooo much!!!!! Handsome man!!!